# How to design a pane with keywords?

Tags: forms, gui-design, interaction-design

We want to enhance the keywording in our [program](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) and for this we plan to add keyword sets organized in panels.

Here is a screenshot from another program which depicts two variants for showing these keyword sets:

[image: Two ways to show keywords]

The blue one is more space saving while it shows the entire text of all keywords.

The red one has the advantage that it can be clicked, but it cuts from the text of some keywords.

My feeling is that the best is a combination of the two: a flowing layout of flat buttons (or clickable labels) showing the entire text of each label. Also IMHO it should auto-adjust its height to its content.

Am I correct? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, I'd suggest that you used an even better implementation of tagging with keywords to write this post.

The problem is that are an almost infinite number of keywords that could be attached to the images that your users could use. Showing recent entries in a list could be great for users that work within the same concepts all the time, and therefore use the same keywords regularly, but more likely each attempt to tag will be very different from the last.

If you use a free textbox and then suggest keywords as they type, you open up two advantages over the list of keywords approach.

1. The user can quickly narrow down many keywords quickly, just three letters splits the total list 17,576 ways.
2. The user can easily add a new keyword that may not be in the applications keywords list.

Once you have the keyword selected or entered, then you can move the model you are proposing above. I would agree that your blue option is more space efficient, and I don't think that forcing the keywords to conform to regular sizing would  help at all.

Comment: Since you agree with me, it seems that 'BLUE' option is more space efficient... :-)

Comment: Erm, yes. Updated!! :-)